# Creating dynamic lambda using helper method

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have a main method that creates a basis search criteria for a given entity. In this method i consequently check for default values before applying it to the query.

E.g.

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            qry = qry.Where(x => x.PropA.Contains(value));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(anotherValue))
            qry = qry.Where(x => x.PropB.Contains(anotherValue));
```

However, I would like to refactor this and use a helper method instead, but since my knowledge and experience with Expressions are somewhat limited I'm having difficulty completing the task.

I have this boiler code which I believe illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
    IQueryable<T> Test<T, TV>(IQueryable<T> qry, Expression<Func<T, TV>> prop, TV value)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<TV>.Default.Equals(value, default(TV)))
            return qry;

        var right = Expression.Constant(value);

        var body = Expression.Equal(prop, right);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body);

        return qry.Where(lambda);
    }
```

Which should enable me to make calls like this:

```
qry = Test(qry, x=>PropA, value);
qry = Test(qry, x=>PropB, anotherValue);
```

The problem however is that the body variable results in a BinaryExpression and I'm totally ignorant in how to proceed from here.

Comment: What if the default value is `-1` and not `0` or `null`? Is this method really increasing readability? I'd prefer your simple code where i see the `if` instead of the hidden `if` "one-liner". Just my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to transform the method into an Expression and then include it as the body of the lambda.

So, starting from your boiler code, after the above changes it should look like

```
    IQueryable<T> Test<T, TV>(IQueryable<T> qry, Expression<Func<T, TV>> prop, string propertyValue)
    {

        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
        var someValue = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
        var body = Expression.Call(prop, method, someValue); // pseudocode, to be refined below

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body);

        return qry.Where(lambda);
    }
```

Now let me rephrase it using a string accessor

```
    static IQueryable<T>  Test<T>(IQueryable<T> qry, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
    {
        var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
        var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);
        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
        var someValue = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
        var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsMethodExp, parameterExp);
        return qry.Where(lambda);
    }
```

Finally a trivial usage example

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public string Myname { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var check = new MyClass() { Myname = "11 aa 22" };
        var check2 = new MyClass() { Myname = "11 bb 22" };
        var x = new List<MyClass>();
        x.Add(check);
        x.Add(check2);
        var q = x.AsQueryable();
        var qry = Test(q, "Myname", "bb");
    }
```

Well, if you prefer a property selector, the helper will become

```
    static IQueryable<T>  Test<T>(IQueryable<T> qry, Expression<Func<T, string>> selector, string propertyValue)
    {
        var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");

        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)selector.Body;
        var parameterTProperty = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
        var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, parameterTProperty);

        MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
        var someValue = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
        var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsMethodExp, parameterExp);
        return qry.Where(lambda);
    }
```

used as

```
        var qry = Test(q, z => z.Myname , "bb");
```